# when an order is placed the quantity of products should be decremet

Tags: python, django, django-models, e-commerce

I am working on ecommerce site. Where I want when order is placed , The product quantity should be decrement by 1. I guess thee change should be done in orders models.py. But what should be the change I do not know
here is my product **models.py** file:

```html
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=110)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    discount_price=models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(choices=SIZE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path)
    description = RichTextField(max_length=1000)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

my  **orders models.py** is :

```html
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self , billing_profile , cart_obj):
        created = False
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(billing_profile=billing_profile, cart=cart_obj, active=True,)
        if qs.count() == 1:
            obj = qs.first()
        else:
            obj = self.model.objects.create(billing_profile=billing_profile, cart=cart_obj)
            created = True
        return obj , created



class Order(models.Model):
    billing_profile     = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order_id            = models.CharField(max_length=120 , blank=True)
    shipping_address    = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="shipping_address" ,null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    billing_aaddress    = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name="billing_address" ,null=True , blank=True , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart                = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status              = models.CharField(max_length=120 , default='created', choices=ORDER_STATUS_CHOICES)
    shipping_total      = models.DecimalField(default=5.99, max_digits=100 , decimal_places=2)
    total               = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100 , decimal_places=2)
    active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id

    objects = OrderManager()

    def update_total(self):
        cart_total = self.cart.total
        shipping_total = self.shipping_total
        new_total = math.fsum([ shipping_total ,cart_total])
        formatted_total = format(new_total,'.2f')
        self.total = formatted_total
        self.save()
        return new_total


    def check_done(self):
        billing_profile = self.billing_profile
        shipping_address = self.shipping_address
        billing_address = self.billing_address
        total = self.total
        if billing_profile and shipping_address and billing_address and total > 0:
            return True
        return False

    def mark_paid(self):
        if self.check_done:
            self.status='paid'
            self.save()
        return self.status





def pre_save_create_order_id(sender, instance, *args,**kwargs):
    if not instance.order_id:
        instance.order_id = unique_order_id_generator(instance)
    qs = Order.objects.filter(cart=instance.cart).exclude(billing_profile=instance.billing_profile)
    if qs.exists():
        qs.update(active = False)


pre_save.connect(pre_save_create_order_id, sender=Order)



def post_save_cart_total(sender, instance,created, *args,**kwargs):
    if not created:
        cart_obj=instance
        cart_total = cart_obj.total
        cart_id = cart_obj.id
        qs = Order.objects.filter(cart__id = cart_id)
        if qs.count() ==1:
            order_obj =qs.first()
            order_obj.update_total()
post_save.connect(post_save_cart_total, sender=Cart)

def post_save_order(sender, instance,created, *args,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.update_total()

post_save.connect(post_save_order, sender=Order)
```

and the **order views.py is**:

```html
class HomepageView(ListView):
    template_name = 'orders.html'
    model = Order
    qs = Order.objects.all()
```

At the end I want to describe that product first goes to the cart the address got called. and both of them comes to the order .

Answer (score 0):

@Huma Qureshi- Your order model is sitting by itself with no relationship with Product. You will need to create a new model called Lets say

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
     order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)    
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

.............
When a order is placed by the user, you need to create this orderitems which will have a record of the order_id,user_id,product_id, and quantity. Once this is created, then on post_save, you can update the product quantity in the Product model.

#post_save of Order creation

```
def update_product_quantity(sender, instance,created,**kwargs):
       if created:
          instance.product.quantity = F('instance.product.quantity') -1
          instance.save()
```